Is it likely that Russia has made fake allegations against Tourists in the past to exchange them as prisoners?
With the recent exchange of prisoners and German politicians explicitly calling travel to Russia irresponsible, this question made me wonder:
Is it irresponsible to travel to Russia as a US citizen or EU citizen because you may be detained and kept prisoner without having done anything wrong? Or have previous prisoners probably done at least something wrong?

A question which manifests prior research would show that the op had read about things  such as the trial of British engineers ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro-Vickers_Affair ).   The probability of person accused of a crime in Russia being innocent is higher than in other, civilized, countries so the answer to your second question is no.  The answer to the first is yes, for the very reason stated in the question.

@C'estMoi the value of an answer to this question exists independent of whether I could find an answer myself.

@C'estMoi if you think prior research necessarily includes reading about trials a hundred years ago, under a different state and a different legal system... I will respectfully disagree.

I find it amusing that the media's assumption is that Western prisoners are innocent patsies, accused by a heartless Russian government of being spies, whereas the Russian prisoners are clearly spies, working undercover. It seems far more likely that everyone involved was up to something

@Valorum due process and fair trials can do wonders.

@Valorum Vadim Krasikov murdered someone in Berlin and the Russians have acknowledged after his release that he is an FSB employee.

@Stefan - I'm 99% certain that this was just a good old-fashioned spy swap. Ours for theirs. And imagining that our spies don't occasionally kill people (when the need arises) is pretty naive.

Here is a list of the prisoners and the crimes they were accused of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2024_Russian_prisoner_exchange#Individuals_released People can draw their own conclusions.


Is it irresponsible to travel to Russia as a US citizen or EU citizen

Yes, for many reasons.

because you may be detained and kept prisoner without having done anything wrong?

While this is unlikely the risk is higher than in most other countries. You do NOT want to give the Russian's even the tiniest excuse.

Or have previous prisoners probably done at least something wrong?

Hard to say. Perter Schoebel had a few gummy bears in his luggage that apparently contained weed. Ksenia Karelina was arrested for donating $50 to Ukraine. Some of the released prisoners were unwanted activists or journalists. For others the picture is murky and we'll never know for sure what really happened.

Tl;dr No, the risk is minimal, but even so is it worth it?
Very few Westerners are arrested in Russia compared to the number of people who visit. You hear about it a lot because when it does happen, it tends to be widely publicized.
Of those that have been, most have broken Russian laws (Griner, Fogel, Karelina - yes, sending money to a country that yours is in armed conflict with is a crime, and not just in Russia). A few (Gershkovich, Kurmasheva) have upset the government with public activity, i.e. beyond just a few tweets (Kurmasheva also technically did break the law, but it's unlikely anyone would have cared if she hadn't already made herself unwelcome). A couple are accused of espionage, which is difficult because you wouldn't expect an admission even if it's true. Spector is probably guilty, Whelan is uncertain. Trevor Reed may be guilty of a crime or may be a victim of police corruption - of course, that can happen without going anywhere. At a minimum, he was drunk and disorderly to the extent that someone called the police.
There does seem to be more risk for dual citizens and others with close ties to Russia, of course causation may be the other way - people with ties to Russia are more likely to do illegal things there.
All this to say - no, Russia is not randomly arresting tourists (they don't want to discourage tourism). You won't get into trouble for anything that wouldn't get a local into trouble. In fact you're rather less likely to have problems, most police don't want to be responsible for an international incident. The risk of being arrest as a regular tourist is minimal, significantly less than the ordinary risks of traveling. It shouldn't stop you if you have a strong reason to visit Russia.
Having said that, the consequences if anything does happen could be extremely serious, so unless there's a good reason to visit Russia specifically I'd recommend considering alternative destinations.
Edit: if you do visit, some advice: coming from a western country, it's possible you'll be taken aside for additional questioning at immigration, it happened to me once in 2022 but not after that. This isn't really anything to be concerned about, it's not much different from interviews you might have at the border in any western country (especially if coming from a less affluent country). Just answer honestly, as you should anywhere. Be aware though that they may ask to check your phone. It's likely to be fairly casual, they scanned my photo gallery for about 5 seconds and didn't look at any messengers, but to be on the safe side you probably don't want to have any pro-Ukraine statements or criticisms of Russia or its government too visible. If you've made any donations, it's not a problem as long as you're not a citizen but I still wouldn't advertise the fact. Once across the border - just don't be stupid. Russian cities are fairly safe as long as you exercise the same level of caution you should anywhere. Don't get drunk out of your mind in a strange city and don't jaywalk. Avoid large gatherings - almost certainly there's no problem, but as a tourist you're probably not able to judge that, so don't risk it. Don't bring in banned drugs, even if you have a prescription.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Or have previous prisoners probably done at least something wrong?

Let's look at the list of prisoners exchanged. Once we exclude Russian citizens and people who hold dual citizenship with Russia (and thus 10x more vulnerable than a regular tourist) we're left with:

Evan Gershkovich, a journalist. Arrested for writing articles about the Russian-Ukrainian war while in Russia. Fair by Western standards? No. Something a regular tourist is likely to be doing? Also no.
Rico Krieger, seemed to be involved with some shady proceedings around the Russia-Ukraine war. It's unclear to what extend the claims about him are true but he was definitely an anti-war activist at the very least.
Patrick Schöbel, arrested for smuggling cannabis gummy bears. Same thing happened with Brittney Griner in 2022. Feels silly here in the West where weed is de-jure or de-facto legal in many places but that's the law in Russia. The UAE has a similar zero-tolerance policy.
Paul Whelan, a shady character involved with the US intelligence community.


Is it irresponsible to travel to Russia as a US citizen or EU citizen because you may be detained and kept prisoner without having done anything wrong?

As long as you don't bring any drugs (including cannabis products, regardless of their legality in your home country) and don't get yourself involved with the Russia-Ukraine war or Russian intelligence services you'll be fine. Russia is not the safest country in the world and has its fair share of street crime, however their government is extremely unlikely to harass you for no reason.

"don't get yourself involved with the Russia-Ukraine war" there is no war.  It's a SVO.  Just talking about the war could get you into trouble. /s

@PeterM that's a myth. There's no law against using the word "war" in casual conversation and it won't cause you problems. If you combine it with criticism of the government, then sure, but it won't be the word "war" that gets you into trouble. Incidentally, I find this mockery of the "SVO" incredibly ironic and hypocritical, given that the US has absolutely, totally not been at war with anyone since 1945...

@user111403 Interesting myth you have there.  And while you can validly criticize the US for all sorts of things, calling it out over "SVO" is pure Whataboutism.

@PeterM whataboutism (n.) - a word used by hypocrites when their hypocrisy is pointed out. The point is not to justify the SVO or criticize the US, it's calling out the lack of acknowledgement by some people that they're all playing the same game.

I've seen that question, and answers, and it's still a myth. Find me an example of someone prosecuted for calling it a war, who didn't combine it with criticism of the war or the government. Anecdotal, but plenty of people I've talked to have used the word in conversation. I've done it myself. Even Putin did it.

@user111403 Last I heard, claiming Russia is at war with Ukraine is the forbidden criticism punishable by death. And yeah, Putin is a regular Joe, sure, great example. It seems that you're a Russian, so clearly you're legally obligated to say that Russia does nothing wrong. It would be good if you'd put that in a disclaimer, otherwise others might actually believe you.

@littleadv not sure your rant is worthy of an answer, but a) you need a new source of information, b) I never claimed that Russia does nothing wrong, and c) I'm not Russian, but have spent plenty of time there both before and since 2022. Which means I'm speaking from actual knowledge and personal experience, not just whatever I read on the internet.

Yeah, here's the thing: you are something I read on the internet. I have actual experience. And just to make sure you're not trying to deflect - between the two of us, I'm not the shill who just showed up on this forum to drum up Russia out of nowhere.

@user111403 Please provide your valid reasoning for calling me a hypocrite when I have never publicly stated any position on the actions of the US military.  Because if you can't do that, then your comments are likely to be seen as an ad hominem attack.

@PeterM apologies for being unclear, I didn't intend to call you personally a hypocrite. I'm just strongly inclined to be dismissive of the term "whataboutism", because 99% of the time (including this case) it's used inappropriately as a response to legitimate accusations of hypocrisy. Again, not that you are necessarily a hypocrite, but the Western countries criticizing Russia over the "SVO" are, and most people there are closing their eyes to it.
